# Multiple =if(isnumber(search))) for excel issue (If text SR or SNR exists, get cells AG, AG and AA)

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

If SNR text exists it gets values of AD6.  If it doesn’t exist it get values of AD6.

If SR exists, it gets value of AA1

I am able to get this working with `=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("SNR "," " & Sheet1!$D6& " ")),Sheet1!AD6,AD6)`
However I cannot seem to include SR.

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("SNR "," " & Sheet1!$D6& " ")),Sheet1!AD6,AD6) AND IF(ISERR(SEARCH("SR "," " & Sheet1!$D6& " ")),Sheet1!AA1,AA1)
```

Is there a way around this issue or is this a limitation of excel?
I have included an image to more accurately convey what I am saying.

[image]

Comment: You can't use AND in this way. It preceeds the multiple conditions you want to evaluate. It is not interposed.

Comment: Also, make your question more specific. The following "If SNR text exists it gets values of AD6. If it doesn’t exist it get values of AD6" , what is 'it'? And if   you get the value of AD6 no matter what, just set 'it' to AD6. No test required. Do you mean =IF(Sheet1!$D6 ="SNR", AD6, IF(Sheet1!$D6 ="SR",AA1, do whatever when neither found))

Comment: Also, your title doesn't match the detail you give in the question i.e. where does AG come into it and AG and AA?

Comment: Instead of AA1 I am trying to use Q6 + F6.  I don't think it lets you refer to the cell you are working in though.  I am wanting the total.  HMMM.  Thanks though that did the trick, I am at one last road block :S

Comment: Q6 = Q6 + F6 ? No.

Comment: I am working in Q6 with =IF(Sheet1!$D6 ="SNR", AD6, IF(Sheet1!$D6 ="SR",AA1
and am wanting to basically change AA1 -> AG6.
And in AG6 I have Q6 (total) + F6 (a number I want to add to that that changes).
Problem is I am working in Q6 so it doesn't like it

I suppose the only solution here is to create a new column.... Hmm thats not an option in this case. HMM

Comment: You cannot have a circular reference where the the result depends on itself in the calculation. I think i used the right term there. The answer still is no you can't. Why can't you have a helper column?

Comment: @QHarr circular references are possible in special cases, but you need to activate iterative calculation. Here is an Example: http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/433-tip-performing-iterative-calculations-in-excel

Comment: @Peh - thanks, i had a sneaking suspicion i was using the term incorrectly. I will have a look at your link. Much obliged.

Comment: You can just use `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!D6,"*SNR*"),Sheet1!AD6,Sheet1!AA1)` if there is only two conditions (SNR or SR).  Otherwise, try this: `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!D6,"*SNR*"),Sheet1!AD6,IF(COUNTIF(Sheet1!D6,"*SR*"),Sheet1!AA1,"Neither Matched"))`